Ubuntu login hangs for ~2 minutes before responsiveness
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. After I log in, there's a consistent 2-minute (approx. 2m 19s) delay before my desktop becomes responsive. Not sure if it helps, but I am running a 3 monitor setup with an NVIDIA graphics card. Applications start without a delay after the desktop is initialized. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Ran systemd-analyze blame and systemd-analyze critical-chain (both system and user) – no service shows a 120s delay.
Removed or disabled Snap packages (including snapd-desktop-integration).
Reinstalled xdg-desktop-portal and related services (portal timeouts no longer appear in logs).
Examined logs via journalctl --user -b -f to look for 2-minute gaps; they occur right after xdg-desktop-portal starts:

dec 16 17:54:50 nexus-l systemd[3375]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
dec 16 17:54:50 nexus-l snapd-desktop-i[17048]: New theme: gtk=Default icon=Adwaita cursor=(null), sound=freedesktop
dec 16 17:54:50 nexus-l snapd-desktop-i[17048]: All available theme snaps installed
dec 16 17:57:02 nexus-l /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[17128]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/zsh
dec 16 17:57:02 nexus-l /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[17128]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SESSION_MANAGER=local/nexus-l:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/5088,unix/nexus-l:/tmp/.ICE-unix/5088
dec 16 17:57:02 nexus-l /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[17128]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dec 16 17:57:02 nexus-l /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[17128]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
dec 16 17:57:02 nexus-l /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[17128]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
...


Removed everything from my startup apps.
Created a new user to test; the same delay occurs.

I’ve also searched for leftover scripts in ~/.xprofile, ~/.xinitrc, ~/.config/autostart/ but the delay persists.
Question:
How can I pinpoint the exact cause of this 2-minute startup delay after login? Are there additional logs or troubleshooting steps I should check beyond what I’ve already tried? If additional info is needed I'll be glad to provide it.
The issue seemed to be with xdg-gnome-desktop-portal timing out during login where timeout was 120000, i tried installing dbus-broker and now i don't get the timeout message in my journalctl logs, but the issue persists, silently(?).

For reference, this has also been asked on Ask Ubuntu in Ubuntu login hangs for ~2 minutes.
